# Buffer Slow In Reading Data From Bluetooth Device

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I am Getting 22 byte of Data from A Bluetooth Device Every 10 milliseconds

Now The Problem is that The Buffer Is Taking more time to read the data so i am missing data from device

```
inputStream = btSocket.getInputStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[22];

 while (inputStream != null ) {
  if (inputStream != null && inputStream.available() > 0) {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        inputStream.read(buffer);
        long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Log.e("time to execute code",stopTime - startTime+"");
```

So I need to finish reading before 10 milliseconds every time

Here Is My Logcat

[image: logcat]

Answer (score 0):

Read with only a byte[] is blocking by itself. You might want to use [read(byte[], int offset, int size)](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28byte[],%20int,%20int%29) to only read the bytes you want.

You can check how many bytes are returned by read(byte[]) by checking its return value.

Comment: Although I just saw that read(byte[]) is equivalent to read(byte[], 0, buffer.length).